# Wimax in XUbuntu?

Tags: wireless, drivers, kernel, xubuntu

I have a problem, I am using the Intel Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150 as wifi and wimax card but I can only use wifi. I googled a lot about drivers and stuff but I can not find the way to activate it. Before installing Ubuntu, I had Windows 7 and wimax worked properly. I don't know what the problem could be, I mean, the actual kernel version has wimax integration but it is not working on my computer, what could it be??

Answer (score 1):

To install the drivers open up the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install madwimax
```

Comment: Note: The Universe repository must be enabled for this to work on mWiMAX equipment based on Samsung CMC-730